# Need a task tree view plugin for Redmine 1.1.2.stable

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Assume I have in Redmine several tasks with 'blocked by' or 'depends on' relations between them. When I look at result of 'my tasks' query Redmine shows all the tasks in a single list. Can you recommend me the plugin which allows users to see only the 'root' tasks and filter all secondary tasks?

Current view is like that:

```
Task 1     (depends on subtask 1.1)
Task 1.1   (blocks parent task 1)
Task 2     (depends on subtask 2.1 and 2.2)
Task 2.1   (blocks parent task 2)
Task 2.2   (blocks parent task 2)
```

How I would like to see that is:

```
Task 1
Task 2
```

Thank you!